# Does a 1951 Convention travel document become invalid after 6 months in a foreign country?

Tags: residency, refugees

My spouse was issued a blue refugee passport (1951 Convention travel document) in an EU country within the Schengen Area, but has legally been resident in the UK for more than 6 months.

We know this makes the residence card which was issued on the basis of his refugee status invalid (automatically expires after 6 months residence abroad).

Is this also the case for a refugee passport? Or does it remain valid until the expiry date printed on the passport?

Comment: The 1951 convention has nothing to say on the matter.  It is therefore controlled by the law of the country that issued the document.  What country was that?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.